# SSL context init failed: Invalid keystore format

Tags: ssl

I am trying to create stub for web services using ANT build. 
Web Application is deployed on Websphere.
I am using default keystore and truststore files of the Websphere.

Following are the arguments I set as ANT_OPTS inside environment variable
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="D:\App Servers\Websphere 8.5\WAS server\profiles\AppSrv02\config\cells\SACHINANode02Cell\nodes\SACHINANode02\trust.p12" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="WebAS"

When I run the build using ANT command I am getting the error as follows

D:\Scrap\July 2013\classes for eqube610>ant generate-client
Buildfile: build.xml

setup:

generate-client:
 [wsimport] Consider using / so that wsimport won't do unnecessary compilation
 [wsimport] parsing WSDL...

[wsimport] [ERROR] Default SSL context init failed: Invalid keystore format

[wsimport] Failed to read the WSDL document: https://sachina.technologic.com:9444/eq610s/eQSOASingleton?wsdl,
 because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of
the document is not .

[wsimport] [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

[wsimport]  At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

[wsimport]     Failed to parse the WSDL.
 [wsimport] Command invoked: wsimport "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre\bin\java.exe" -d
"D:\Scrap\July 2013\classes for eqube610\build" -g -keep https://sachina.technologic.com:9444/eq610s/eQSOASing
leton?wsdl -p com.eqtechnologic.eqube.webservice

BUILD FAILED
D:\Scrap\July 2013\classes for eqube610\build.xml:35: wsimport failed

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Far as I know the standard JDK only supports JKS type keystore format. So the options -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="D:\App Servers\Websphere 8.5\WAS server\profiles\AppSrv02\config\cells\SACHINANode02Cell\nodes\SACHINANode02\trust.p12" that you are specifying are causing issues - JVM is not able to parse the P12 file as keystore. What you need to do is create a JKS keystore using keytool utility and import the certificate into that and then retry.

Comment: @Parry Hi parry thanks for your reply.
As you said I created keystore using IBM ikeyman tool.
The file named key.jks got created.
I specified the path of that key.jks file into ANT_OPTS as follows.
ANT_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="D:\App Servers\Websphere 8.5\WAS server\profiles\AppSrv02\etc\key.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="bhushan"
Now I am getting following error.
[wsimport] [ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmPara
meterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you import the certificate into the jks file using keytool? If you have an empty Keystore you'll get that error.

Comment: @Parry thanks again for your valueable reply.
Here is what I did so far: I created keystore file named key.jks using websphere ikeyman tool. Then I created certificate named certreq.arm using New Certificate Request option in ikeyman tool. 

My guess : Now I think next I have to import the certificate into the jks file. After importing truststore file will be created. Then I need to use truststore file path in my ANT_OPTS option. 

Questions : 1) Am I guessing correctly as above? Please correct me.
2) Please let me know how to import certificate into the jks file using Websphere tools. Thnks

Comment: You need to use the JDK Keytool command to import certificate. (The one you created is a cert request - that needs to be convered to a signed certificate which you then import into the JKS.) Read up a little on PKI and Java docs on certificates/keystores/keytool. I am afraid I can't give you directions specific to your requirements - you'll need to come up with those after reading up. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Parry Thank you so much. 
Actually I have done this whole process of generating the keystore, export the certificate and then import for Tomcat. Is it the same process I need to follow for websphere as well?
Following are the commands I used successfully for tomcat.
For generating keystore
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
For export
keytool -v -export -file mytrustCA.cer -keystore C:\Files\.keystore -alias tomcat
For import
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file "C:\Files\mytrustCA.cer" -keystore "C:\Files\.truststore" -storepass bhushan

Can I use the same process for Websphere?

Comment: Is there any body who can help me? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance